# Flash Player 10 real-time audio playback

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, audio

I'm trying to playback some sample data through the new real-time audio capabilities of Flash Player 10. I started with the example given at the bottom of [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html) page on livedocs, which seems to work fine and plays a crystal clear tone.

I assume that the two `writeFloat`'s in the example write to the left and right audio channels respectively and that the data being written is 32 bit (because of the float).

However. I seem to be having trouble converting my old 8 bit audio data to a format that is understood by this interface. When I playback my sample data I can vaguely hear the sound I'm expecting but it is massively distorted. My sample data consists of raw 8 bit samples that ranges from 0..255 where 127 is silence.

I've been trying different conversion formulas but I seem to be missing some vital information regarding this conversion.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The correct formula turns out to be:

```
f = (sample.data.readByte() - 127) / 255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the conversion var newSample:Number = (Number(oldSample)-127.0)/127.0;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are reading in your 8-bit data correctly. If you are using the ByteArray-class then use readUnsignedByte (instead of readByte) to get a value between 0-255. Then use the formula suggested by MontyGomery.